# Capture keyboard input in JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, console

I 'm writing a JUnit test that has to wait for user's input before running; the scenario is something like:

- Beginning running the test
- Wait for some external operation that **cannot** be automated/mocked to complete; user has to perform some manual activity and then notify the test to continue
- Continue running

I tried to use

```
System.out.println( "Press enter to continue" );
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
reader.readLine();
System.out.println( "Resuming..." );
```

but it doesn't work, as System.in doesn't seem to accept input from the keyboard within a test.

I know this is not a typical / orthodox unit test, but I'd like to code it as one since it is then convenient to use Maven to test various cases.

Can I do that, or I should move my test to a normal (i.e. non-Junit) program?

Thanks

Comment: You are stating the solution you imagined for a problem. If you tell us what the actual problem is, we may be able to offer better ideas / alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If it requires user input it is not really a unit test - don't treat it as such.

Just make it as a simple program, which is easy to run, and then do the test when required. It makes no sense to include that in your build, so it should be run on a different schedule - not per build, but something more in line with your development process - per day, per new feature, etc.

Comment: Yes it's not really a unit test, the semantics are entirely different I just like the run facilities. I was wondering if this is possible in JUnit, I guess I'll make it a program.